# Why is [].concat() faster than Array.prototype.concat()?

Tags: javascript, performance

I tested various array concatenation techniques not because it actually matters to my code but merely as an aside, to see where we are right now. As expected the very new ES 2015 spread operator is beaten by the old `concat()` method on JavaScript arrays by a considerable margin.

However, what surprised me a bit was when I compared these two:

```js
var a = b = c = [1,2,3,4,5];

// SLOWER (V8 and Edge, very slightly faster in Firefox)
console.time('t1');
for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  Array.prototype.concat(a, b, c);
};
console.timeEnd('t1')

// FASTER (V8 and Edge, very slightly slower in Firefox)
console.time('t2');
for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  [].concat(a, b, c);
};
console.timeEnd('t2')
```

I tested, and ran multiple times before doing the next one, on the latest Node.js, Chrome and Edge browsers. With V8 (Node.js, Chrome)  the result is even bigger, but even for Edge the first option is always clearly - on V8 significantly - slower than the second option. In Firefox results are reversed but almost equal, so let's limit the question to the other two browser engines (V8 and Chakra).

So I'm asking merely out of curiosity, since I did not foresee this at all,

1) Apart from performance, is there any practical difference between the two ways to concatenate those arrays?

2) Why is the one that AFAICS creates one object (array) less than the other (the initial array) *slower*?

---

I know the methods are the same, that's why I tested the direct access to the method on the prototype instead of creating an (unused) array object to access it. I also know that it's browser dependent, which is a) why I tested two V8 based systems (Chrome and Node.js) and the Microsoft Edge browser, and b) why I included the runnable test case above.

Comment: `Array.prototype.concat` and `[].concat` is the same thing, so most likely your testing is faulty.

Comment: You can run my test, which is why I included it. What would be faulty? Please tell me!

Comment: Did you try swapping them, and running the last first instead etc.

Comment: Yes, I tried a lot of combinations, thsi is just how I wrote it for the SO question. I ran each one multiple times before running the other one multiple times.

Comment: In my browser (Firefox 45 ESR) t1 is faster than t2.

Comment: `Array.prototype.concat(a, b, c)` and `[].concat(a, b, c)` aren't the same functionally - they are the same function sure, but the 2nd one has the context of an instance.

Comment: Is just an idea, `Array.prototype.concat` and `[].concat` are the same, we know that, buy may be when executing, the compiler all ready knows what `[]` is instead of going through `Array.prototype`, as I say is an idea, because I also suppose the compiler change `[]` for `Array.prototype`...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Array.prototype.concat` needs to be resolved in every loop. If you would lookup the function only once, you'll see different results. This may vary depending on the implementation of the runtime though.

```js
var a = b = c = [1,2,3,4,5];

// Array.prototype.concat
console.time('t1');
var apc = Array.prototype.concat;
for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  apc.call([], a, b, c);
};
console.timeEnd('t1')

// [].concat
console.time('t2');
for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  [].concat(a, b, c);
};
console.timeEnd('t2')

// They're the same:
console.log(Array.prototype.concat === [].concat);
```

To get more accurate results, use a proper benchmarking library (eliminates warm up time for example).

Comment: That's the answer! Can't mark it thus for another 10 minutes. I really don't see why I got downvoted to -4 within SECONDS when only this post of all those commenting actually got the correct answer.

Comment: Very nice answer and explanation!

Comment: You're on to something, but why does it have to be resolved on every iteration when the full properties etc. are used to reach that function, and why not when the shorter `[]` is used, I mean after all `Array.prototype.concat === [].concat` is true ?

Comment: Actually it's heavily browser dependant. Chrome: t1 slower than t2. Firefox: t1 faster than t2, but both 10x slower than Chrome. Internet Explorer: both similar fast, slightly slower than Chromes t2. My conclusion would be that IE already optimizes the function to be resolved only once. Firefox probably does that too but is slower in general.

Comment: Exactly. I would have thought that modern JS engines optimize such actually trivial things? By the way, in addition I found that the difference in Edge goes down a lot when you run the test for much longer. It seems a lot of effort is constant. So it pays to run such tests in varying length loops and not just in one. That was not the case with V8 based engines.

Comment: Yes, most JS engines actually need to warm up, which means it will be faster as it runs longer etc.

Comment: I agree on that this can be browser dependent. :) Added this remark.

Comment: Yes, you are right, you have with `var apc = Array.prototype.concat;` it become faster then `[].concate(a,b,c);` but you have mot make resolution variable for testing speed of `[].concate;`, if you make resolution variable  for var apc1= [].concate; and call it in loop then it will be faster then first resolution

Comment: @HareshVidja I just tried that in the node.js REPL and got the same results for both.

Comment: Wrong explanation. The call should be `apc.call(context, a, b, c)` with `const context = Array.prototype` (compare with `const context = []`). And then it is slow again. So it has nothing to do with the lookups (outside of the concat function at least).

Comment: @RobertSiemer If you could post your findings as an answer, I'll gladly remove my answer. More accurate information is more important than votes for me.

Comment: Wow, very sportsmanlike. I added an answer. Not sure if removing your answer is possible or even the best thing to do, though... (If you do, I’ll update my answer to reflect that.)

Answer (score 0):

**The accepted answer is inaccurate.** In Chromium the code below shows that the difference in execution is not related to outside lookups, but to the context, i.e. `this` inside `concat()`. (In Firefox, the advantage of `[].concat()` is marginal and not even consistent.)

In the `[].concat()` case the context is an empty array, whose elements will be included in the concatenation result. With `Array.prototype.concat()` the context is `Array.prototype`, which is also an array, also “empty” in the “array-sense”, but full with methods... I’m not sure *why* this makes such a difference.

Update: I was playing around with a custom made array: one with many non-number members, i.e. length === 0. It took twice the time compared to the empty array, but still not as slow as `Array.prototype`...

```js
const a = b = c = [1,2,3,4,5];

const ap = Array.prototype;
const apc = Array.prototype.concat;
const array = [];

function loopAndLog(msg, context) {
  console.time(msg);
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    apc.call(context, a, b, c);
  };
  console.timeEnd(msg)
}

loopAndLog('[].concat() equivalent first round', array);
loopAndLog('Array.prototype.concat() equivalent first round', ap);
loopAndLog('[].concat() equivalent second round', array);
loopAndLog('Array.prototype.concat() equivalent second round', ap);
```